# Is tree-level QCD on-shell constructible, with BCFW?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, yang-mills, s-matrix-theory

Is tree-level QCD on-shell constructible, with BCFW?
Pure yang mills is on-shell constructible, what is one add into massless fermions?

Comment: sorry, what if ....

Comment: Please spell out your acronyms. What is BCFW?